How to correctly set up MSAL on an Azure DevOps Extension?
I'm making an Azure DevOps Extension and I want to integrate it with an Azure Function App using MSAL.
I have it all correctly set up.
Microsoft App Registration, the MSAL objects, I can get the Token and do the request to the Azure Function correctly.
The problem is the Redirect Uri I'm using when I'm creating the PublicClient object.
As for now, my code looks like this:
import { PublicClientApplication } from "@azure/msal-browser";
return new PublicClientApplication({
            auth: {            
                    clientId: Constants.Microsoft_AppID,
                    authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/"+ Constants.TenantID,
                    redirectUri: window.location.href,                   
              }
          });

the URI given by the extension when using window.location.href looks something like https://[organization].gallerycdn.vsassets.io/extensions/[organization]/[extension-name]/[version]/[timestamp]/dist/WorkItem/WorkItemForm/WorkItemForm.html
As you may see, the version of the extension and the timestamp changes every time I deploy a new version of the Extension. So, in order to make it work, I have to add this new URL to my Microsoft app allowed redirect URI's list.
(I can't add wildcards when allowing redirect URIs, it must be an exact URI)
I would like to have an static URL as a redirect URI, which I don't really know how to get it, cuz if use every other URI like "https://dev.azure.com/[organization]/" the window that pops out when the msal is initializing stays blank and nothing happens
This gives me the idea I'm doing something wrong. Either I misunderstood the documentation, or I'm missing something, but I don't think this is expected to work like this.
Maybe I should be using some another service? Not doing this at all?

I'm using the popup login flow but it needs a redirect uri anyway.
Thanks, I'm currently doing research about how to configure an Api Gateway.
In case it works I will post it as the solution

Any update on this?

Yes, I've posted the solution I found.

Best solution I found:
I've created an Api Management on Azure, and I pass the origin in the State variable, but its a bit tricky.
I created 2 endpoints. /Callback and /Redirect
On my typescript code, I set /Callback as redirect uri (and of course, I registered on my App Registration) and send the origin url on the State parameter
import { PublicClientApplication } from "@azure/msal-browser";
this.Instance = new PublicClientApplication({
            auth: {            
                    clientId: Constants.Microsoft_AppID,
                    authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/"+ Constants.TenantID,
                    redirectUri: "https://MyApiManagement.azure-api.net/auth/callback"                   
              }
          });


this.Instance.Initialize();

const iframeUrl = window.location.href;         
const authResult = await this.Instance.loginPopup({
       scopes: ["User.Read"],
       state: JSON.stringify(iframeUrl)                
});


the state parameter is used to keep alive anything you need during all the authentication flow, it even checks if it has been modified in the middle of it (and if it has been modified, then it fails the authentication).
Then, at the Api Management /Callback resource, I have the following inbound policie's
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <return-response>
            <set-status code="200" reason="OK" />
            <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
                <value>text/html</value>
            </set-header>
            <set-body><![CDATA[
                    <!DOCTYPE html>
                    <html lang="en">
                    <head>
                        <meta charset="UTF-8">
                        <title>Processing Authentication</title>
                        
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        <p>Processing authentication...</p>
                    </body>
                    <script>
                                    
                            (function() {
                                const Target = "https://MyApiManagement.azure-api.net/auth/Redirect"

                                const fragment = window.location.hash.substring(1);          

                                document.body.innerHTML += "<p>looking for fragment parameters \n</p>";

                                const queryString = `?redirected=true&${fragment}`;                                    
                                const redirectUrl = `${Target}${queryString}`;

                                document.body.innerHTML += "<p>\n redirect url = " + redirectUrl + "\n </p>";  
                                                              
                                window.location.replace(redirectUrl);                               
                                
                            })();
                        </script>
                    </html>
                    ]]></set-body>
        </return-response>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>


This resource emulates a website.
It must exist as the redirection from the App Registration pass all the parameters as fragment parameters, so like https://MyApiManagement.azure-api.net/auth/Callback#Code=1234&State=1234...
And in order to read them correctly in the inbound policies, they need to be in the query string.
/Callback turns https://MyApiManagement.azure-api.net/auth/Callback#Code=1234&State=1234... into https://MyApiManagement.azure-api.net/auth/Redirect?Code=1234&State=1234... (fragment parameters into query string parameters and redirection to my 2nd endpoint)
at /Redirect I have the following policies
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(context.Request.Url.Query.ContainsKey(&quot;state&quot;))">
                <set-variable name="state" value="@context.Request.Url.Query.GetValueOrDefault(&quot;state&quot;)" />
                <set-variable name="queryAsFragment" value="@{
                        var queryParams = context.Request.Url.Query;
                        var fragmentBuilder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                        foreach (var param in queryParams)
                        {
                            if (fragmentBuilder.Length > 0){
                                fragmentBuilder.Append("&");
                            }
                            string KeyValue = string.Join("", param.Value);                                  

                            fragmentBuilder.Append(param.Key).Append("=").Append(Convert.ToString(KeyValue));
                        }                                
                        return fragmentBuilder.ToString();

                    }" />
                <return-response>
                    <set-status code="302" reason="Found" />
                    <set-header name="Location" exists-action="override">
                        <value>@{
                            string encodedState = context.Request.Url.Query.GetValueOrDefault(&quot;state&quot;);
                            string encodedReplaced = encodedState
                            .Replace("%257c","|")
                            .Replace("%257C","|")
                            .Replace("%7C","|")
                            .Replace("%7c","|")
                            .Replace("%2522","")
                            .Replace("%22","");

                            string[] parts = encodedReplaced.Split('|');
                            if (parts.Length < 2)
                            {
                                throw new Exception("State parameter is invalid or malformed. Original: " + encodedState + " \n - Modified: " + encodedReplaced);
                            }                                    
                            return ( ((string) Uri.UnescapeDataString(parts[1] ))  + "#" + ((string)context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault(&quot;queryAsFragment&quot;)).Replace("|", "%7c") );
                        }</value>
                    </set-header>
                    <set-header name="Cache-Control" exists-action="override">
                        <value>no-store, no-cache</value>
                    </set-header>
                    <set-header name="Pragma" exists-action="override">
                        <value>no-cache</value>
                    </set-header>
                    <set-header name="Access-Control-Expose-Headers" exists-action="override">
                        <value>Location</value>
                    </set-header>
                </return-response>
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <return-response>
                    <set-status code="400" reason="Bad Request" />
                    <set-body>Missing or invalid state parameter</set-body>
                </return-response>
            </otherwise>
        </choose>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>

/Redirect is doing the following:

It reads all the parameters and join them into a new string.
The state parameter will always have the following format state=[some base64 encoded object]%7c][your origin url UriEncoded] so we are splitting them with %7C (wich is the code for '|' character) and we keep the original url as we want to be redirected there.
We return a 302 (Redirection code) to the Url that has been found, + "#" (fragment parameters) + AllTheParameters as they have arrived.

The result is
https://MyApiManagement.azure-api.net/auth/Redirect?Code=1234&State=1234|https://google.com.ar...
is turned into
Https://google.com.ar#Code=1234&State=1234|https://google.com.ar...
So when the redirection is complete, it has all the parameters (code, object, state, etc) as fragment parameters, and Msal can read, check and authenthicate as it needs.
This can be done using just one endpoint redirecting to itself? Yes. You could also do all the query manipulation and redirect to the original url in one resource. I decided to have 2 separate endpoints for better understanding.
Hope this helps and that is understandable. Ask in the comments if you want me to clarify something
